# Error when referencing .Net Standard 2.0 library from Asp.Net 4.7 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I have an MVC project targeting asp.net 4.7.
And i have created a class library which targets .Net standard 2.0

If i reference the class library from my MVC Project i get the following exception on application startup.

> System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found:
>
> Message   "Method not found:
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1
>   System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.get_MessageHandlers()'."

At

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

If i remove the reference everything is back to normal.
Any ideas that may be wrong with that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add this binding redirect to web.config:

```
<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Also, refer to the Nuget package [System.Net.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http/) into all component

Answer (score 0):

If your mvc project targets .net 4.6.1 you can use a .net standard 2.0 class library with it.